# Boundary decision with knn-classifier

Tags: r, knn, boundary

I want to find the boundary-decision function in order to classify my data. Here is an example of them.

```
 "Distance","Dihedral","Categ"
    4.083,82.267,C
    4.132,87.073,C
    4.713,-80.999,C
    3.427,-48.144,NC
    3.663,96.994,C
    3.99,71.919,C
    3.484,78.684,C
```

So far I've got the knn model but I'd like to plot the non-linear decision boundary. In the examples I have searched, there are some variables that I don't have a clue where to use them or what do they mean. I'm talking about this example I found in "The Elements of Statistical Learning" book

```
library(ElemStatLearn)
require(class)
x <- mixture.example$x
g <- mixture.example$y
xnew <- mixture.example$xnew
mod15 <- knn(x, xnew, g, k=15, prob=TRUE)
prob <- attr(mod15, "prob")
prob <- ifelse(mod15=="1", prob, 1-prob)
px1 <- mixture.example$px1
px2 <- mixture.example$px2
prob15 <- matrix(prob, length(px1), length(px2))
par(mar=rep(2,4))
contour(px1, px2, prob15, levels=0.5, labels="", xlab="", ylab="", main=
        "15-nearest neighbour", axes=FALSE)
points(x, col=ifelse(g==1, "coral", "cornflowerblue"))
gd <- expand.grid(x=px1, y=px2)
points(gd, pch=".", cex=1.2, col=ifelse(prob15>0.5, "coral", "cornflowerblue"))
box()
```

What exactly are px1 and px2? Do I need similar variables for my particular case?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I think px1 and px2 are simply vector describing the grid for the new data, i.e. the points along x and y axis where you have new data.

Answer (score 1):

I have reworked and annotated the example to make it clear what happens.

The example constructs a test set that is simply an expanded grid that convers the entire test set.  Thus px1 is a vector that describes the x-component of the grid of the test data, and px2 is similar, but for y. Then `xnew` is the result of `expand.grid()`.

Try the following code, where this should be reasonably clear. I have also modified the k-value, and provided an easy way to construct `xnew` using intervals of your choice.

```
library(ElemStatLearn)
require(class)

# Use the training data from mixture.example
x <- mixture.example$x
g <- mixture.example$y

# Construct a test grid using the extent of the training data
xx_range <- round(range(x[, 1]), 1)
xy_range <- round(range(x[, 2]), 1)

nnn <- 0.1
px1 <- seq(xx_range[1], xx_range[2], by = nnn) # vector with x extent
px2 <- seq(xy_range[1], xy_range[2], by = nnn) # vector with y extent
xnew <- as.matrix(expand.grid(px1, px2))       # matrix of new values

# Train a model
k <- 10
mod15 <- knn(x, xnew, g, k=k, prob=TRUE)
prob <- attr(mod15, "prob")
prob <- ifelse(mod15=="1", prob, 1-prob)
prob15 <- matrix(prob, length(px1), length(px2))

# Plot the results
par(mar=rep(2,4))
contour(px1, px2, prob15, levels=0.5, labels="", xlab="", ylab="", main=
          sprintf("%d-nearest neighbour", k), axes=FALSE)
points(x, col=ifelse(g==1, "coral", "cornflowerblue"))
points(xnew, pch=".", cex=1.2, col=ifelse(prob15>0.5, "coral", "cornflowerblue"))
box()
```

[image]